# Error Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>

Tags: typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I have the above error, I couldn't figure out what problem is, I am using `react-router-dom` with `typescript`:

```
import React from "react";
import Nav from "./components/Nav";
import Main from "./components/Main";
import About from "./components/About";
import { BrowserRouter , Route, Switch, Link } from "react-router-dom";
const App: React.FC = (props) => {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            {/* <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <Link to="/about">About</Link>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav> */}
            <Nav pages={[{ name: "main", path: "/" }]} />
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact>
                    <Main>
                        <h1>Test</h1>
                    </Main>
                </Route>
                <Route path="/about">
                    <About>
                        <h1>About page</h1>
                    </About>
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
};

export default App;
```

and the `Nav` component:

```
import React from "react";
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
type NavProps = {
    pages: NavItem[];
};
type NavItem = {
    path: string;
    name: string;
};
const Nav: React.FC<NavProps> = (props: NavProps) => {
    return (
        <nav>
            <ul>
                {props.pages.map((page) => (
                    <li key={page.name}>
                        <Link to={page.path}>{page.name}</Link>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </nav>
    );
};
export default Nav;
```

It just doesn't make any sense clearly the `Link` is rendered inside `Nav` which in turn rendered inside `BrowserRouter`, am I missing something here?

If I replaced the `Nav` component, with:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
            <Link to="/about">About</Link>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

...this hardcoded snippet the error goes away.

and this is the app entry `index.tsx`:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./app";

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById("app")
);
```

Comment: The code you showed looks fine. Maybe the import of `BrowserRouter` is incorrect, or you're rendering an additional `<Nav>` somewhere else?

Comment: I believe that invariant error is a v6 error, but your code is using v5 components and syntax. First let's verify what version you think you are using. What is specified in your package.json file and what is *actually* installed by running `npm list react-router react-router-dom` from the project's root directory. Second, please let us see a complete code example, a [mcve], so we've full context for what the code is doing.

Comment: @DrewReese they are both  version `5.3.3`

Comment: And the full, complete and reproducible code example?

Comment: That's pretty much it, there is the `webpack.config.js` I can post that as well.

Comment: So the files are not importing anything? Ok, please show where `BrowserRouter`, `Switch`, `Route`, `Nav`, etc are declared, and where the first snippet's JSX is being rendered.

Comment: Ok let me post the whole thing

Comment: I don't see any overt issues with the code you've shared and I'm unable to reproduce any errors in a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/error-invariant-failed-you-should-not-use-link-outside-a-router-4ux386). Perhaps like Nicholas says, you've mixed up *some* import or you are rendering another `Nav` component elsewhere *outside* a router.

Comment: Ok thank you I really appreciate your effort.

Comment: Are you using SSR?